# dojo Select onChange works only once

Tags: javascript, select, dojo, onchange

my Dojo widget Select fires only by the first change. All other change events do nothing.

```
        var selectServerAddServices = new Select({
            name : "selectServer_forAddService",
            style : {
                width : '180px'
            },
            onChange: function() {
                  alert("test ");
                 }
        });
```

What can be the Problem?
The Options of the Select is set by store.

Comment: Is it the same thing if you use `selectServerAddServices.on("change", cunction(){})`?

Comment: yes its the same, both way's dosent work

Comment: Looks like you're doing something wrong then: http://jsfiddle.net/gxy2G/

Comment: Oh the Problem is the id in the store, i added an object to the id because i have more values. Like this: ...id: {"value1":x, "value2":y}

Comment: Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/gxy2G/1/ but how can i do it right in the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use objects as IDs. What happens behind the screens is that, when you change the value of the `dijit/form/Select`, it will first validate if the old value is different from the new value by using the `dijit/form/Select::compare()` function. This function is implemented as:

```
compare: function(/*anything*/ val1, /*anything*/ val2){
    if(typeof val1 == "number" && typeof val2 == "number"){
        return (isNaN(val1) && isNaN(val2)) ? 0 : val1 - val2;
    }else if(val1 > val2){
        return 1;
    }else if(val1 < val2){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Which means that, in order to be different, your id must be either smaller or bigger than the previous id.

However, when you compare objects, this does not work, for example:

```
var a = { id: 1 };
var b = { id: 2 };
a < b; // Returns false
b < a; // Returns false
```

So, even when the properties are different, the comparison always returns false, so both objects are treated as "equal", which means that the `onChange` event is not triggered.

---

To solve this issue, you have to change the implementation of the `compare()` function, for example:

```
var selectServerAddServices = new Select({
    name : "selectServer_forAddService",
    style : {
        width : '180px'
    },
    compare: function(val1, val2) {
        return (val1.id1 - val2.id1) + (val1.id2 - val2.id2);
    },
    onChange: function() {
        alert("test");   
    }
});
```

Now it will check both your ID properties, which should make the `onChange` trigger in each case. I also updated the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gxy2G/3/